# IBMMQ Get Message Exception

Tags: .net, ibm-mq, mq

I have a windows service which listens to the MQ Queue and receives the messages.Sometimes i get the below exception and loose some messages. Does anyone has experienced this before? Below is the exception

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at IBM.WMQ.MQDestination.Get(MQMessage message, MQGetMessageOptions gmo, Int32 maxMsgSize)
   at IBM.WMQ.MQDestination.Get(MQMessage message, MQGetMessageOptions gmo)
 System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
    at IBM.WMQ.MQDestination.Get(MQMessage message, MQGetMessageOptions gmo, Int32 maxMsgSize)
    at IBM.WMQ.MQDestination.Get(MQMessage message, MQGetMessageOptions gmo)
```

This is the code i use to receive the message

```
                props.Add(MQC.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, "xx.xx.xx.xxx");
                props.Add(MQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, "Test");
                props.Add(MQC.PORT_PROPERTY, "1420"));
                props.Add(MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_MANAGED);
                props.Add(MQC.CONNECT_OPTIONS_PROPERTY, MQC.MQCNO_RECONNECT_Q_MGR);
                queueManagerrecieve = new MQQueueManager("test", props);                  

                queuerecieve = queueManagerrecieve.AccessQueue("test",
                         MQC.MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF + MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING);
```

Comment: Have you seen a patten when this exception is thrown? Is there something different on the message that is causing the exception to be thrown?

Comment: Just figured out that when the message broker is down it is causing the exception

Comment: I expect a MQRC 2009 connection broken exception to be thrown.if queue manager goes down while MQQueue.Get is called.

Comment: What version of MQ client and queue manager are you using? Hope it's not v6.

Comment: am using MQ Client 7.5 and Queue Manager 7.5

Answer (score -1):

Given the MQ version this probably the reason.

IC88182: A DOTNET APPLICATION RECEIVES NULLREFERENCEEXCEPTION INSTEAD OF A WEBSPHERE MQ RETURN CODE.
https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/apar/IC88182

Bug in the MQ version with the available fix.

Comment: That bug was fixed at 7.0.1.10 which was released before 7.5, so this is likely unrelated.